# javascript, Fron end Development

Tags: javascript, frontend

I'm trying to change the Highstock names. names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG']; To names = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE']; I want to change the names by any names. Please Help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var seriesOptions = [],
        seriesCounter = 0,
        names = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'];
    /**
     * Create the chart when all data is loaded
     */
    function createChart() {

        Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 4
            },

            yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                    }
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 2,
                    color: 'silver'
                }]
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    compare: 'percent',
                    showInNavigator: true
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                valueDecimals: 2,
                split: true
            },

            series: seriesOptions
        });
    }

    $.each(names, function (i, name) {

        $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {

            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: name,
                data: data
            };

            // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
            // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
            seriesCounter += 1;

            if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
                createChart();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when i change these names Chart does not load. Any kind of Help Apreciated. How can i change these names please help. Thanks

**Original Code.**

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; margin-bottom:20px;"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var seriesOptions = [],
        seriesCounter = 0,
        names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'];
    /**
     * Create the chart when all data is loaded
     */
    function createChart() {

        Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 4
            },

            yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return (this.value > 0 ? ' + ' : '') + this.value + '%';
                    }
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 2,
                    color: 'silver'
                }]
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    compare: 'percent',
                    showInNavigator: true
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                valueDecimals: 2,
                split: true
            },

            series: seriesOptions
        });
    }

    $.each(names, function (i, name) {

        $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {

            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: name,
                data: data
            };

            // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
            // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
            seriesCounter += 1;

            if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
                createChart();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The chart is being populated with values from the line:

```
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
```

where `name.tolowercase()` takes the value of the names variable

```
names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'];
```

and fetches content from the file:

https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=msft-c.json&callback=?

https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?

https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=goog-c.json&callback=?

So when you replace with 
    names = ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE'];

it does not find corresponding files on the server

https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=one-c.json&callback=?

Hope it helps :).

The files will need to be placed on the server with relevant data for the charts to load.

Comment: Thanks for your Response Tphil. How can i add these files to my local server or localhost?

Comment: You can run the files in a local hosting environment. A really simple way could be found here - [link](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/06/22/nodejs-setup-simple-http-server-local-web-server).  
You can place your files inside this folder. 

If you do however have a running server. Then you should navigate to the serving directory & place files there. The location will vary depending on the  server in use.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error when you want to get a JSON response for the files 'one', 'two' and 'three', for that reason the chart doesn't load.

To handle that exception I suggest you to use the jQuery's Ajax methods `.fail()` and `.always()` like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/number_phi/ch4pqxmn/).

If you see my example, the chart loads, even without data.